# Understanding Hatcher's corollary 4.25

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

[image]

Here he proved the cyclic groups is infinite by considering the degree, but the degree is from $H^n(S^n)\to H^n(S^n)$, how is this related to the homotopy group $\pi_n$?. Moreover, how does $z\to z^k$ has degree $k$ imply $\pi_n(S^n)\to\mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: You know the group is cyclic, so you just have to show it is infinite. Since maps of different degree cannot be homotopic...

Comment: @SteveD Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

He use the Hurewicz theorem to identify $\pi_n(S^n)$ to $H_n(S^n)$
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem

Comment: Thank you, but that corollary is before Hurewicz theorem in the textbook, so  he doesn't mean to use the  Hurewicz theorem i guess.